# Using ES7 static propTypes with React-Native

Tags: react-native, ecmascript-next

When I'm launching my project using React-Native default packager, I have this error: `Unexpected token` on this line:

```
static propTypes = {
   /// ...
};
```

I took a look on React-Native issues on  GitHub, but I didn't find a solution.

Any suggestion?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After @Fomahaut answer, I keep looking on Facebook's GitHub repository and found this issue: https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/2182

- Create a .babelrc file at the project's root directory
- Add more rules to Babel

Example:

```
    {
      "retainLines": true,
      "compact": true,
      "comments": false,
      "whitelist": [
        "es6.arrowFunctions",
        "es6.blockScoping",
        "es6.classes",
        "es6.constants",
        "es6.destructuring",
        "es6.forOf",
        "es6.modules",
        "es6.parameters",
        "es6.properties.computed",
        "es6.properties.shorthand",
        "es6.spread",
        "es6.tailCall",
        "es6.templateLiterals",
        "es6.regex.unicode",
        "es6.regex.sticky",
        "es7.asyncFunctions",
        "es7.classProperties",
        "es7.comprehensions",
        "es7.decorators",
        "es7.exponentiationOperator",
        "es7.exportExtensions",
        "es7.functionBind",
        "es7.objectRestSpread",
        "es7.trailingFunctionCommas",
        "regenerator",
        "flow",
        "react",
        "react.displayName"
        ],
      "sourceMaps": false
    }
```

Comment: This doesn't work with newer versions of react-native, probably due to the switch to Babel 6.

Comment: Not sure about "whitelist" or this specific use case, but a top-level .babelrc file with "plugins" defined works great for me with RN 0.19+.

Answer (score 7):

React-Native packager use Babel for transfer ES6 and ES7, but NOT ALL features. The enable list is [here](https://github.com/facebook/react-native/blob/master/babel-preset/configs/main.js). In your case, [class-props](https://babeljs.io/docs/plugins/#experimental) is not enabled by default in RN packager. You can use Babel to compiler your code before packager, or just enable it in the packager setting. See this [official doc](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/javascript-environment.html#content) for more information.

Answer (score 4):

Try appending your propTypes to your class:

```
var MyClass extends React.Component {
....
}

MyClass.propTypes = {
.... /* enter proptypes here */
}
```

Comment: @skypecakes ¯\_(ツ)_/¯

Comment: Your example is specific to ES6. The OP requested help with ES7. That's probably why the downvote.

Answer (score 3):

According to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34018355/37168), you need to install a plugin for class properties as of Babel 6.

> As of Babel 6, you now need the [transform-class-properties](http://babeljs.io/docs/plugins/transform-class-properties/) plugin to
>   support class properties.

Steps:

1. Run this: `npm install babel-plugin-transform-class-properties`
2. Add this to your .babelrc: `"plugins": ["transform-class-properties"]`
   (Note, it's a plugin, not a transform; so don't put it in the "presets" list.)

Worked for me.

Answer (score 1):

Install the [stage-0 Babel preset](http://babeljs.io/docs/plugins/preset-stage-0/) (`npm i --save-dev babel-preset-stage-0`) and add it to `.babelrc` file's `presets` section, e.g.:

```json
{ "presets": ["react", "es2015", "babel-preset-stage-0"] }
```

Answer (score 0):

See if that helps:

1. `$ npm install babel-plugin-transform-decorators`
2. navigate to `/<your project root>/node_modules/react-native/packager/react-packager/.babelrc`
3. Add `"transform-decorators"` to this list:

   `{
     "retainLines": true,
     "compact": true,
     "comments": false,
     "plugins": [
       "syntax-async-functions",
       "syntax-class-properties",
       "syntax-trailing-function-commas",
       "transform-class-properties",
       "transform-es2015-arrow-functions",
       "transform-es2015-block-scoping",
       "transform-es2015-classes",
       "transform-es2015-computed-properties",
       "transform-es2015-constants",
       "transform-es2015-destructuring",
       ["transform-es2015-modules-commonjs", {"strict": false, "allowTopLevelThis": true}],
       "transform-es2015-parameters",
       "transform-es2015-shorthand-properties",
       "transform-es2015-spread",
       "transform-es2015-template-literals",
       "transform-flow-strip-types",
       "transform-object-assign",
       "transform-object-rest-spread",
       "transform-react-display-name",
       "transform-react-jsx",
       "transform-regenerator",
       "transform-es2015-for-of",
       -->"**transform-decorators**"<--
     ],
     "sourceMaps": false
   }`