# React es7 static childContextTypes unexpected token

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm still very new with react, and still learning with es7.

I got a problem:

```
import React from 'react';
import MessageList from './MessageList.jsx';
import mui from 'material-ui';

var ThemeManager = new mui.Styles.ThemeManager();
var Colors = mui.Styles.Colors;
var AppBar = mui.AppBar;

class App extends React.Component {
  constructor(){
    super();

    ThemeManager.setPalette({
      primary1Color: Colors.blue500,
      primary2Color: Colors.blue700,
      primary3Color: Colors.blue100,
      accent1Color: Colors.pink400
    });
  }

  static childContextTypes = {
    muiTheme: React.PropTypes.object
  }

  getChildContext(){
    return {
      muiTheme: ThemeManager.getCurrentTheme()
    };
  }

  render() {
    return(
      <div>
        <AppBar title="Awesome" />
        <MessageList />
      </div>
      );
  }
}
export default App;
```

when i tried to compile using webpack-dev-server it return me error

```
Module build failed: SyntaxError: D:/learn/react2/src/components/App.jsx: Unexpected token (21:27)
}

static childContextTypes = {
                         ^
      muiTheme: React.PropTypes.object
}
```

I compile it using babel with

```
"presets": ["react", "es2015"]
```

What should i do to make it work?

I'm using latest react (0.14.4).

Thanks

Comment: did you eventually figure it out? if so, would you mind  providing the solution using your example?

Answer (score 2):

As of Babel 6, you now need the [transform-class-properties](http://babeljs.io/docs/plugins/transform-class-properties/) plugin to support class properties.

Comment: linking to outside documentation on whats changed really doesn't help. what is the solution? in this example?