# react-native-tab-navigator npm module showing unexpected token at static proptypes

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

while using react-native-tab-navigator npm module ,i am getting errors like unexpected token on this line like

```
static propTypes = {
   /// ...
};
```

But while reading this article [Using ES7 static propTypes with React-Native](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33615537/using-es7-static-proptypes-with-react-native) the error bcs of Using ES7 static propTypes with React-Native.
But how to access  .babelrc file in my project

Answer (score 0):

So in root of your project, create a file call .bablerc and then paste in the instruction of the other StackOverflow question you found should do the trick.